# Play audio-file from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, audio, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to play a song that I've put in assets. (this is the path: app/assets/audios/Jean.mp3), but I always get an error on the get-request, what am I doing wrong?

This is the code I use to play the file:

```
<button onclick="playAud()" type="button">Play</button>

<audio id = "audio" autoplay>
    <source src= 'app/assets/audios/jean.mp3' type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script> 
var audio = document.getElementById("audio"); 
   function playAud() { 
        audio.play(); 
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now it works

I've added this to the helper file:

```
def audio_path(source, options = {})
    path_to_asset(source, {type: :audio}.merge!(options))
end
```

and changed the code in the view-file to this:

```
<audio src="<%= audio_path 'jean.mp3'%>" type="audio/mpeg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```